# Use variable from one file to another file

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have the following file called as test1.sh which contains:

**File 1**: `test1.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

a=10
b=11
if [ $a == $b ]
then
    message="A is equal to b"
else
    message="A is not equal to b"
fi
```

**Note**: Now i have second file called as `test2.sh` in which i want to print the message variable of file one that is `test1.sh`.

**File 2**: test2.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
.... /*How to get the message variable from file test1.sh */
echo $message
```

Comment: Have you tried searching http://stackoverflow.com, rather than posting a new question here, as it doesn't directly concerns Ubuntu?

Comment: How are you going to run the two scripts? What's their relation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `source`. (I assume that both files are in the same location)
In test2.sh add `. test1.sh`